# Connection Issue With Mysql,JDBC on Red Hat Linux

Tags: java, mysql

I am implementing a class that needs to connect to a MYSQL database....on a windows system, i had some connection issue which were resolved with changing the "bind-address" paramater in the MYSQL configuration file to localhost and setting the MYSQL connector in the classpath.
I tried the same steps on Red Hat Linux,..but no connection is made. Is it something with the security configuration?. Below is the code i am using to test for a MYSQL connection.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class test {
    static Connection con = null;

    public static void main(String[]args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {

        //Load Driver

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();               
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/IMS","root","root1");
            System.out.println("Database Connected");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("error connecting database: little challenge" + e);
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
}
```

The error being returned is

```
error connecting database: 
    little challenge java.sql.SQLException:
    Unexpected exception encountered during query.
```

I believe this means the connection is not being made. How can i resolve this?

Comment: You should print the stacktrace, not only the exception's `toString`. Call `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Just a side node: the product is called MySQL, not MYSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem related to use of GCJ. It relates to the connection attempt raising an exception when it reaches an unknown character or one it cannot convert.

Recommendation: use Hotspot (a.k.a. Sun) JVM.

Update: To do so, install the JDK rpm and use `alternatives` command to set the default JVM version as shown on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/259905/removing-all-traces-of-gnu-java-and-openjdk-and-replacing-with-sun-jdk).

Comment: Ok....the current version of java i am using is from the GNU libgcj version 4.*....how can i change this to a jdk rpm downloaded from Oracle Website?

Comment: alternatives option was giving me errors in Red Hat...opened the ./bash_profile  file using vi...and then added the path like this:PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin....worked perfectly....and a +5 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Define port of server

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/IMS
```

Comment: I dont think it requires port

Comment: so you can not connect without port

Comment: If it's not set, the conn goes on 3306 by default

Comment: I never used port for mysql on linux,may be it was taking default port

Answer (score 0):

You have to add mysql jar file in project.After its work also on linux.